# How to create a function with a range in R?

Tags: r, function, range

I want to define the function `f(x) = (2/pi) * sqrt(1-(x^2))` and its range `[-1,1]`. I don't think there's a Indicator Function in R, but how can I define this range?

Answer (score 1):

What about this kind of function definition?

```
f <- function(x) {
  stopifnot(abs(x)<=1)
  (2/pi) * sqrt(1-(x^2))
}
```